# After importing the script into Unity3D, the first character of the script is replaced with "_"

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm just download Unity 2020.1.14f1.
After importing the script into Unity3D, the first character of the script is replaced with "_".
Is it a bug?

[Video](https://youtu.be/AclbCxmnets)

Comment: Only one script with a specific name or every script?

Comment: Every script...

Comment: I reinstalled Unity but still  have this issue

Comment: [It's a known bug in various versions of the Unity editor.](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/files-are-renamed-when-dragged-into-unity-using-file-explorer?_ga=2.112209537.402098992.1605827982-805308937.1604518206).

Comment: I'll be waiting for fix :) Thx!